# What is the best approach to find all fields that has (Foreign Key and Primary Key) constraints in a Mysql database?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, primary-key, constraint

I have a mysql database that has 250 tables. 
I would like to run a query to retrieve:
tableName ; FieldName  ; ConstaintName (Primary or foreign key).

I could use information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS to retrieve the constarint type
but for the inner join I have no idea what should I use.

What is the best approach to achieve this task?

EDIT:
not Constraint name. Should be CONSTRAINT_TYPE instead of ConstaintName. So we should be able to see (Primary or foreign key) only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [INFORMATION_SCHEMA KEY_COLUMN_USAGE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/key-column-usage-table.html) table.

```
SELECT
table_name AS TableName,
column_name AS ColumnName,
Constraint_name as ConstraintName
FROM
information_schema.key_column_usage
WHERE table_schema = 'database_name'
```

**Updated code based on OP's requirement:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT(TC.table_name) AS TableName, KC.column_name as ColumnName,
TC. CONSTRAINT_TYPE AS ConstraintType
FROM 
information_schema.table_constraints TC,  
information_schema.key_column_usage KC  
WHERE
TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('FOREIGN KEY', 'PRIMARY KEY') 
and KC.table_name = TC.table_name and KC.TABLE_SCHEMA = TC.TABLE_SCHEMA
and KC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
and KC.table_schema = DATABASE();
```

Comment: Hi Friend, you are correct but I commited a mistake. I dont want the ConstaintName. I need the value of the CONSTRAINT_TYPE column.

Comment: Hey Friend, that works fine.

Comment: @zwitterion Sounds good..